# Equations and the use of \\ before the environment

Tags: equations

What is the best way to handle this? Using `\\`, a free line or just no space between the text and the environment?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Mathematik

\begin{document}
    Should I put the equation with no line break directly behing this text? 
    \begin{equation}
        a = b
        \label{eq:ab}
    \end{equation}
    And follow with text here? Same more text to make the amount of white space easier visible. \\
    
    Or should I do it like this? Some more text.
    
    \begin{equation}
    a = b
    \label{eq:ab}
    \end{equation}

    And go on with a line space? \\
    
    Or should I put a line break on the end of the line before the equation? \\
    
            \begin{equation}
            a = b
            \label{eq:ab}
            \end{equation}
    
    And leave a line space between this text and the equation?   \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all you should never put blank lines in the source above displayed math.  Secondly you should never have the need to use ``\\`` in the text. If yuo do then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you. How to break a line correct without \\? 
I take your answer as indicator that the first version is correct: no blank line or \\ before displayed math.

Comment: Why would you want to break a line? TeX is able to do it by itself.

Comment: I might start to understand a thing I have done wrong for years. Line break and new line is not the same. I guess, what I want to do usually is starting "new line". What code should I write for a "new line"? What code should I write for a new paragraph?

Comment: A new paragraph is started by adding a blank line in the code. Note that 99.999% of times displayed math never starts a new paragraph, so no blank lines above those

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few golden rules:

1. never use `\\` in normal text (see final note);
2. never have a blank line in front of a math display;
3. a blank line after a display is permitted, provided the text starts a new paragraph (which isn't frequently the case).

“Math display” means anything of the form `\[...\]`, `equation`, `equation*`, `align`, `align*`, `gather`, `gather*` and the other `amsmath` environments for displays such as `multline`.

So the correct input is

```
I should not have a blank line before the math display, like here
\begin{equation}
  a = b
  \label{eq:ab}
\end{equation}
and no blank line after it, unless the text really starts a new paragraph.
```

**Final note.** Using `\\` to end lines is of course allowed in `tabular` (actually necessary, in this case), in `center`, `flushleft` or `flushright`. In ***VERY RARE*** occasions `\\` might be useful in normal text, but notice that I used all caps in boldface italic in order to emphasize the concept. This “very rare” means that I might have used it just a handful of times in the few decades I've been using LaTeX and for very special effects.

Comment: Concerning point (2.) and (3)., are there ways to make sure this is possible? It greatly increases the readability (for me) when there is gaps before and after equations.

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar Use a nonblank line with just `%`. I've been writing LaTeX for about 30 years and I've never felt the need to have more than `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` on lines by themselves. But I understand other people's needs. A “really blank” line before a display would spoil the output.